# How can I print a form that include a RichEdit in Delphi 2007?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I am currently working on a project with a really easy task : When I press a button, the form I'm currently in is printed (like a print screen).

I use the method Self.Print; in the said button and everything works fine. My buttons, labels and TextBoxes all get printed. The problem is, I have a RichEdit in the form I'm trying to print and when the page come out of the printer, the RichEdit is blank.

I know there is much better ways to print informations from a form, but this is the current way that the button has to work.

I've found some forums with topics from 2003 that said it was either not possible or I had to use the RichEdit.Print method but this means having 2 pages coming out of the printer instead of one.

Is there a better way to print the whole package?

Comment: You could capture the form to a graphic (like a PNG or Bitmap) and print that.

Comment: Is all the content of the RichEdit visible on-screen, or is there some that has to be scrolled into view?

Comment: It depends on what the user of the application has written in the RichEdit so there is a possibility that a scroll would be needed to see the end of the text.

Comment: If that's the case, then the only way to do it reliably would be to use some kind of reporting tool like Fast Reports, Rave or Report Builder to produce the formatted output you require.

Comment: Then you're pretty much out of luck. Windows does not paint the area of the window that isn't visible; calling RichEdit.Print handles drawing the off-screen content in a specialized fashion. You're probably at the point where you need to actually design a report rather than just trying to print the screen.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for the quick answers! I will ask the client if printing the RichEdit on a separated sheet would be ok.

Answer (score -2):

```
RichEdit1.Print(RichEdit1.Text);
PrintDialog1.Execute;//Choose your printer from list
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.